# How to know what host is being called

Tags: c#, redirect, web

I have a web app in C#  and I want to redirect the app depending on the host being called on the site... for example if I call www.domain.com I want the app to be redirected to a folder called Site1  if I call www2.domain.com I want the app to be redirected to Site2. these are example names.. it's the same site different operations. All the DNS stuff is being taken care of, so no worries. I must say that www and ww2 are pointing to the same server IP address.

Thanks a lot guys..

(Sorry if the title is not too clear, I didn't knew how to ask the question properly)

Comment: sound you need proxy / load balancer

Comment: Try to Google IIS bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should inspect `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`.

Example:

```
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
switch (host.ToLower())
{
    case "www.domain.com":
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Site1");
        break;
    case "www2.domain.com":
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Site2");
        break;
    default:
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @john-wu :)  I remember seeing this code.. but I couldn't fetch it again from google.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS you can [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of hosting your web app (e.g. IIS, self-hosted). Since you haven't said, I'll assume you're using IIS. You can simply add two different websites, each with an HTTP (port 80) binding for the appropriate host name (i.e. www.domain.com for one, www2.domain.com for the other). This can be configured when you add the site, or later using the bindings dialog.

If you want this to work with HTTPS, the fact that you're using a single IP address means you'll need to be able to support [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This is only available in IIS from version 8 onwards (Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8).